# How to get a midpoint of a line and a square(openGL)

Tags: opengl, variable-assignment

Do I need to look for a formula to get the midpoint? Or there is already a function in openGL that allows me to do so.

I thought up a code that some I think that is close:

```
    if(num1 % 2 == 0)
    {

    }
```

What I mean is for the line to get the midpoint (openGL)

```
    glVertex3f(-3,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(3,0.0,0.0);
```

Comment: You are going to have to elaborate on what you mean by "midpoint of a line and a square".

Comment: FWIW, the conditional in your first code block returns true if `num1` is even - not sure what that has got to do with finding a midpoint...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the midpoint of a line segment (as your edit implies), it's simple linear algebra:

```
//  Where p1 and p2 are your line end points.
midpoint = p1 + ( ( p2 - p1 ) * 0.5 )
//  Or...
midpoint = ( p1 + p2 ) * 0.5;
```

Comment: Can you make an openGl of a box with a cross in the middle? I find that very challenging.

Comment: I can, yes.  I suggest you learn basic geometry before tackling computational geometry, as with anything it's difficult at first but becomes much easier once you know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

> Or there is already a function in openGL that allows me to do so.

**OpenGL is not a math library!** It just draws things, and that's how it should be.

Comment: Although I agree with you completely, this doesn't answer the main question the OP asked.

Comment: @cbamber85: The question of the OP was if OpenGL can be used for it, or if he has to implement it himself. The question is not clear about what kind of geometrical calculation he does want to have, but it can be clearly stated, that OpenGL is not to be used for this.

Comment: @T_01: Elaborate please? Last time I checked drawing things is the *only* purpose of OpenGL.

Comment: OpenGL is just a definition or a set of definitions for communicating with the gpu. its only a specification. What actually does drawing thing (or actually does send commands to the gpu, because drawing things is actually the gpu...) is an implementation of OpenGL.

Comment: @T_01: That's splitting hairs… and in the wrong way. Following that kind of implementation you could just as well say that the `read(2)` / `write(2)` / `ReadFileEx` / `WriteFileEx` are not performing I/O operations, because those are just interfaces specified by POSIX or Win32. Or – same principle – that it's not construction companies that build houses, but very particular construction workers. Going anal over these kinds of semantics doesn't help anybody. On a system you have a particular OpenGL implementation available, and for all intents and purposes that **is** OpenGL then.

Comment: i think if wikipedia says "Open Graphics Library (OpenGL)[3][4] is a cross-language, cross-platform application programming interface" it is not really spitting hairs. But well - you are right, read write and read something are really just interfaces implemented on your system.